# define a function-like macro in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, macros

Is it possible to define a macro-function in bash so when I write:

```
F(sth);
```

bash runs this:

```
echo "sth" > a.txt;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Arbitrary syntax can't be made to do anything. Parentheses are *metacharacters* which have special meaning to the parser, so there's no way you can use them as valid *names*. The best way to extend the shell is to define functions.

This would be a basic `echo` wrapper that always writes to the same file:

```
f() {
    echo "$@"
} >a.txt
```

This does about the same but additionally handles stdin - sacrificing `echo's` `-e` and `-n` options:

```
f() {
    [[ ${1+_} || ! -t 0 ]] && printf '%s\n' "${*-$(</dev/fd/0)}"
} >a.txt
```

Which can be called as

```
f arg1 arg2...
```

or

```
f <file
```

Functions are passed arguments in the same way as any other commands.

The second echo-like wrapper first tests for either a [set first argument](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/083), or stdin coming from a non-tty, and conditionally calls printf using either the positional parameters if set, or stdin. The test expression avoids the case of both zero arguments and no redirection from a file, in which case Bash would try expanding the output of the terminal, hanging the shell.

Comment: +1, nice answer. would you mind to explain more detailed why you use that more complex (but better) construct to output the argument(s)?

Comment: It just allows input from either stdin or arguments. The test expression prevents a situation where there are both zero args and stdin is coming from a terminal, in which case the shell would have to be killed since the processes own tty is getting read and blocking. If that passes then either the positional parameters will be expanded if set, or the expansion will be read from the function's input. A slightly more portable but slower solution is possible with `cat` - this requires a system with real /dev/fd/*. I just posted this trick since my previous answer was the same as the others. :)

Comment: also, it does allow *multiple arguments* just like `echo` does. Your function works with `f one two three` while the others only work with `f "one two three"`. Given input without the qotes, the other solutions would only take the first word (here: "one") into account.

Comment: would be great if you could include those explanations in your answer, so others can learn from that.

Comment: Added a bit of an explanation. It could get even more complex to handle the same features as echo but that seemed a bit outside the scope of this question and would require some option parsing

Answer (score 8):

```
F () {
  echo "$1" > a.txt
}
```

You don't use parentheses when you call it. This is how you call it:

```
F "text to save"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, only you should call it with `F sth`:

```
F()
{
  echo "$1" > a.txt
}
```

Read more [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions).

Answer (score 3):

This was answered long ago, but to provide an answer that satisfies the original request (even though that is likely not what  is actually desired):
This is based on [Magic Aliases: A Layering Loophole in the Bourne Shell](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/aliases.html) by Simon Tatham.

```
F() { str="$(history 1)"; str=${str# *F(}; echo "${str%)*}"; } >a.txt
alias F='\F #'

$ F(sth)
$ cat a.txt
sth
```

See also ormaaj's [better magic alias](https://gist.github.com/ormaaj/5a969c62bab8d21fe468).